# Using AppleScript to compare filenames without extensions in two directories

Tags: applescript

To preface, I made a Photoshop batch action which converts a folder with thousands of images in different formats into .pngs. Unfortunately some of them were skipped and others converted with the wrong aspect ratio.

I'm hoping to compare the folders using Applescript. At the moment I just want to find which files made it through and which didn't. I'd like the user to be able to select the source and converted folders, and then need to strip the file extension to compare the filenames in each folder. Here's what I have written so far; it seems to stop right after the `end tell` statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
--Set folder paths
display dialog "Choose the source folder containing images with correct aspect ratios"
set source_folder to (choose folder)

display dialog "Choose the folder containing PNGs to compare to"
set png_folder to (choose folder)

--Create lists of folder contents for each folder
tell application "System Events"
    set source_filenames to name of every file of source_folder
    set source_extensions to name extension of every file of source_folder

    set png_filenames to name of every file of png_folder
    set png_extensions to name extension of every file of png_folder
end tell

--Collect names (filename minus dot and extension)
set source_names to {}
repeat with n from 1 to count of source_filenames
    set source_filename to item n of source_filenames
    set source_extension to item n of source_extensions

    if source_extension is not "" then
        set source_filename_length to (count of source_filename) - (count of source_extension) - 1
        set end of source_names to text 1 thru source_filename_length of source_filename
    else
        set end of source_names to source_filename
    end if
end repeat
return source_names

set png_names to {}
repeat with n from 1 to count of png_filenames
    set png_filename to item n of png_filenames
    set png_extension to item n of png_extensions

    if png_extension is not "" then
        set png_filename_length to (count of png_filename) - (count of png_extension) - 1
set end of png_names to text 1 thru png_filename_length of png_filename
    else
        set end of png_names to png_filename
    end if
end repeat
return png_names

--Compare each item of source folder to png folder
repeat with n from 1 to the count of source_names
    set theFile to (item n of source_names)
    if theFile is in png_names then
        log "Match found for file " & theFile
        set foundFile to true
    else
        log "No match found for file " & theFile
        set foundFile to false
    end if
end repeat
```

Later, I'll want to compare aspect ratios (using this thread as a guide http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=38308) and have all the files which either didn't get converted or were converted with the incorrect aspect ratio put into some sort of list.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself! Shouldn't be returning source_names/png_names.